# Python - Delete from Array while enumerating

Tags: python, arrays, deep-copy, pyobjc

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "/Users/georg/Programmierung/Glyphs/Glyphs/Glyphs/Scripts/GlyphsApp.py", line 59, in __iter__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc/_convenience.py", line 589, in enumeratorGenerator
    yield container_unwrap(anEnumerator.nextObject(), StopIteration)
objc.error: NSGenericException - *** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x7f9906245480> was mutated while being enumerated.
```

I know this error occurs because I'm trying to delete objects from the array while also enumerating these objects. But I don't know how to solve it. I'm fairly new to object orientated programming and am limiting myself to scripting.

I searched the web and it seems to solve the error, I have to copy the array before deleting objects from it. When I'm tying to copy the array via deepcopy

```
import copy
pathcopy = copy.deepcopy(thisLayer.paths)
```

right before `for path in thisLayer.paths:`

But in this case I get the following error:

```
Cannot pickle Objective-C objects
```

Usually the program crashes after the first Glyph. For clarification: I work in Glyphsapp, a Typedesigning software.

Here is the Code:

```
# loops through every Glyph and deletes every path with nodes on the left half
    for myGlyph in Glyphs.font.glyphs: 
        glname = myGlyph.name   
        thisLayer = Glyphs.font.glyphs[glname].layers[1]
        middle = thisLayer.bounds.size.width/2+thisLayer.LSB
        thisGlyph = thisLayer.parent

        for path in thisLayer.paths:    # this is where the code crashes
            for thisNode in path.nodes:
                if thisNode.position.x < middle:
                    #print thisNode.position.x
                    try:
                        thisLayer = path.parent()
                    except Exception as e:
                        thisLayer = path.parent
                    try:
                        thisLayer.removePath_ ( thisNode.parent() )
                    except AttributeError:
                         pass
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could collect the items to be deleted in a separated list and after that you use another for loop over that list to delete them inside of thisLayer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Andreas,

with your help I was able to fix my code :-)

Here is the outcome:

```
for myGlyph in Glyphs.font.glyphs:
    glname = myGlyph.name   
    thisLayer = Glyphs.font.glyphs[glname].layers[1]
    middle = thisLayer.bounds.size.width/2+thisLayer.LSB
    thisGlyph = thisLayer.parent

    for path in thisLayer.paths:    
        for thisNode in path.nodes:
            if thisNode.position.x < middle:
                nodeList = []
                nodeList.append(thisNode.parent())
    nLCopy = nodeList[:]
    for ncontainer in nLCopy:
        thisLayer.removePath_ ( ncontainer )
```